Android - NotificationBuilder large icon getting pixilated
I create notification and set large icon in builder using bitmap.
I debug that bitmap its getting proper with 1024*1024 size but still after add into notification its show me pixilated(blurry)
 notificationBuilder?.setLargeIcon(bitmap) // using this we load bitmap you can check in below code

Here is code for Generate Notification
fun generateNotification(isPlaying: Boolean? = null): Notification {
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(mService, CHANNEL_ID)
    createNotificationChannel()
    notificationBuilder.setStyle(style)
    notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    mediaSession.isActive = true
    val state = if (isPlaying == true) PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING else PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED
    playbackStateBuilder.setState(state, mService.getCurrentPosition(), mService.getPlaybackSpeed())
    val playBackState = playbackStateBuilder.build()
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playBackState)
    mediaSession.setCallback(callback)
    val mediaMetadataBuilder = MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
    mediaMetadataBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, mService.getDuration())
    mediaSession.setMetadata(mediaMetadataBuilder.build())

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(mContentIntent)
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.itunes)
        .setContentTitle(mService.getCurrentMediaItem()?.mediaMetadata?.albumTitle ?: "")
        .setContentText("${mService.getCurrentMediaItem()?.mediaMetadata?.subtitle} Episodes")
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_TRANSPORT)
       
    val artworkUri = mService.getCurrentMediaItem()?.mediaMetadata?.artworkUri
  
    if (artworkUri != null) {
        artworkUriMap[artworkUri] = notificationBuilder
        loadImage(artworkUri) 
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mService.resources, R.drawable.itunes)
        )
    }
    val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
    mNotificationManager?.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    return notification
}

private fun loadImage(uri: Uri) {
    albumArtFutureTarget?.cancel(true)
    albumArtFutureTarget = Glide.with(this.mService.baseContext)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(uri)
        .override(512, 512)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.itunes)
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Bitmap?> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Bitmap?>, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                val notificationBuilder = artworkUriMap[model]
                notificationBuilder?.setLargeIcon(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mService.resources, R.drawable.itunes)
                )
                mNotificationManager?.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder?.build())
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(bitmap: Bitmap, model: Any, target: Target<Bitmap?>?, dataSource: com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                val notificationBuilder = artworkUriMap[model]
     ////===========HERE IS LOAD BITMAP===========
                notificationBuilder?.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                mNotificationManager?.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder?.build())
                return false
            }
        })
        .submit()
}

Notification SS:

